# Am I able to sell a Steam licensed game that I don't play anymore?

Tags: steam

I have some games that has been registered to my steam account, but I am not playing anymore.

Can I sell off to someone else who wanted to play?

Comment: In accordance with a recent EU law, all dematerialised content should be made avalaible for resale.
But ATM, Steam does not provide this possibility...

I'll try to retrieve that law, and provide a link. You could try to contact their support, maybe someone would be able to provide you with an estimated date about the upcoming of the resale-possibility.

(Please excuse any mispelled or misused words, i'm french =P)

Comment: @Lysarion the EU decision may have... less impact than you'd like with respect specifically to dematerialised content tied to services like Steam. It's too early to say as no administrative interpretations or rulings based on the court decision have yet been handed down, but the wording can be read to provide enough wiggle room to prevent any serious change in the status quo.

Answer (score 9):

No you cannot. This is part of the agreement you agreed on when you linked the game to your account. Therefor is also cannot be regarded unfair. As the comment suggests though there are a few new interesting developments, but so far no one really knows what they mean. Hopefully we will be able to force steam (and all other companies) to enable us to sell what we own, but for now, we cannot.

Evidence of this provided by Joseph Kendall: [Steam Support Link](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417#usedgames)

Comment: To add a bit of evidence, here's the part of their trading FAQ where they note that any game that has been added to your library may not be traded again: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6748-ETSG-5417#usedgames

Comment: @JosephKendall Thanks, I forgot to do so, I'll edit it in!

Comment: The problem with this is. I am not selling for profit and I am not distributing it e.g. copying.

Comment: @Simon By all means, let Steam know. If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it :)

Comment: @Assile while currently _correct_, I'm pretty sure it's not the answer Simon was _hoping_ for :-/

Comment: @Zommuter I feel like he wanted a 'yes'. But what I'm trying to ask him is to approve the answer if he feels it answers his question: "Am I able to sell a Steam licensed game that I don't play anymore?"

Answer (score 1):

In fact in Europe YES YOU CAN LEGALLY by court ruling, see link

http://www.webpronews.com/you-can-resell-your-steam-games-in-europe-2012-07

Comment: Yes, the ruling is you can, but we have yet to see anything that says Valve has to support the sale.